# Both methods have same erasure, yet overrides the other

Tags: java, data-structures, compiler-errors

I'm trying to implement a Queue but my method "enqueue(E e)" is giving me an error saying that the method clashes with the method in the Queue interface but neither override the other. What is going on?

Here is the Queue Interface

```
public interface Queue<E> {
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in the queue.
 */
int size();
/**
 * Tests whether the queue is empty.
 */
boolean isEmpty();
/**
 * Inserts an element at the rear of the queue.
 */
void enqueue(E e);
/**
 * Returns, but does not remove, the first element of the queue (null if empty).
 */
E first();
/**
 * Removes and returns the first element of the queue (null if empty).
 */
E dequeue();
}
```

And here is the implementation

```
/**
* Implementation of the queue ADT using a fixed-length array.
* @param <E>
*/
public class ArrayQueue<E> implements Queue {
    // instance variables
    private E[] data;
    private int f = 0;
    private int sz = 0;
    public static final int CAPACITY = 1000;

    // Constructors
    public ArrayQueue() {
        this(CAPACITY);
    }
    public ArrayQueue(int capacity) {
        data = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
    }

    // methods
    /**
    * Returns the number of elements in the queue
    */
    public int size() {
        return sz;
    }
    /**
    * Tests whether the queue is empty.
    */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return sz == 0;
    }
    /**
     * Inserts an element at the rear of the queue.
     */
    public void enqueue(E e) throws IllegalStateException {
        if (sz == data.length)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Queue is full");
        int avail = (f + sz) % data.length;
        data[avail] = e;
        sz++;
    }
    /**
     * Returns, but does not remove, the first element of the queue (null if empty)
     */
    public E first() {
        if (isEmpty())
            return null;
        return data[f];
    }
    /**
     * Removes and returns the first element of the queue (null if empty)
     */
    public E dequeue() {
        if (isEmpty())
            return null;
        E answer = data[f];
        data[f] = null;
        f = (f + 1) % data.length;
        sz--;
        return answer;
    }
}
```

I've tried removing the "throws new IllegalStateError" and copy and pasting to make sure the spelling was the same. I can't figure out what the problem is. Both of these code fragments come straight out of a book...

Comment: You need to have `public class ArrayQueue<E> implements Queue<E>`.

Comment: That was it! Thanks. I hate when it's something simple like that...